# How to disable contact grouping in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin

Pidgin groups my contacts by protocol and by contact groups. I would like to remove this grouping and sort my contacts alphabetically only.

Comment: Pidgin does _not_ group contacts by protocol.

Comment: @grawity you're right. But since each protocol has different names for their default groups, it seems like it is grouping by protocol.

Comment: Well, you can regroup contacts easily - create a group, select all, drag, drop, remove empty groups.

Comment: Facebook over XMPP does though - regardless of groups, after every restart, all facebook buddies are put in the "Facebook Friends" group. There is a feature request for this: https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/1325 - wontfixed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently there's no way to do so automatically. You can set grouping to manual or alphabetical, and drag all your users into the 'root' group, however.

Answer (score 19):

I just renamed the second group as the first group. then pidgin asked whether I want to merge. I said yes, and now I have only one group. problem solved.

Comment: Super. This should be the answer :) +1